# Export .doc file with openoffice in Window XP, bug failed in linux

Tags: java, linux, openoffice.org

In my project, when I execute next code in Window XP, it can run successfully.

```
XStorable xStorable = (XStorable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XStorable.class, xDoc);
    PropertyValue[] storeProps = new PropertyValue[2];
    storeProps[0] = new PropertyValue();
    storeProps[0].Name = "Overwrite";
    storeProps[0].Value = Boolean.TRUE;
    storeProps[1] = new PropertyValue();
    storeProps[1].Name = "FilterName";
    storeProps[1].Value = "MS Word 97";
    try {
        //Linux: storeUrl = file:///home/user/export/paper/16/xxx.doc
        //Window XP: storeUrl = file:///C:/export/paper/16/xxx.doc
        log.info("storeUrl = " + storeUrl);
        xStorable.storeAsURL(storeUrl, storeProps);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.toString());
        throw new ServerErrorException(e);
    }
```

Bug when I deploy it to linux, there will be a exception: com.sun.star.task.ErrorCodeIOException.
The version of openoffice in linux is OOo_3.3.0.
I want to know how to solve it?